# Oracle SQL - Sum and group data by week

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have records related to dates:

```
DATE         AMOUNT
16.03.2013   3
16.03.2013   4
16.03.2013   1
16.03.2013   3
17.03.2013   4
17.03.2014   3
```

I know how to sum them up for each day, but how could I sum them up by week?`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT to_char(DATE - 7/24,'IYYY'), to_char(DATE - 7/24,'IW'),SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY to_char(DATE - 7/24,'IYYY'), to_char(DATE - 7/24,'IW')
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a037d/1)**

---

*Output would be:*

```
+-----+-------+--------+
|YEAR | WEEK  | AMOUNT |
+-----+-------+--------+
|2013 | 11    | 18     |
|2013 | 13    | 3      |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Works nicely! Modified it to SELECT to_char(DATE - 7/24,'YYYYIW'), SUM(AMOUNT)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY to_char(DATE - 7/24,'YYYYIW')

Comment: I don't understand why the "-7/24". Why substract 7 hours? What is the benefit of this? In fact, subtracting 7 hours from Monday morning could push the date to Sunday and as such show the previous week, which would be wrong.

Answer (score 41):

You can use [`TRUNC`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm#SQLRF51945) function to truncate date to the first day of week. There are [a few ways of defining week](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions255.htm#SQLRF52058). For example, if you want to treat that the first day of week is Monday, you can `IW` format, like this:

```
select trunc(date, 'IW') week, sum(amount)
from YourTable
group by trunc(date, 'IW');
```

You can also `TO_CHAR` function as the "@Vignesh Kumer"'s answer.

The point is that you should truncate the date in the same week into one value. Then group by the value. That's it.

Comment: I suggest you mention that in this scenario it's important to `trunc(date,'IYYY')` and group by it as well (similar to Vignesh's answer), otherwise the same weeks from different years will be grouped into one.

Comment: @Andrejs I'm confused by your assertion that grouping by the week needs to be combined with grouping by the year. `trunc(date, 'IW')` appears to return a full date such as "2023-12-25".  Shouldn't grouping by that be sufficient to group by a week in a particular year?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would help as well....

```
 /* Weekly sum of values */
 SELECT SUM( Amount ) as Sum_Amt, 
 DATEPART (wk, Date) as WeekNum
 FROM databse_name.table_name
 GROUP BY DATEPART (wk, Date)
 ORDER BY WeekNum

 /* Monthly sum of values */
 SELECT SUM( Amount ) as Sum_Amt, 
 DATEPART (mm, Date) as MonNum
 FROM databse_name.table_name
 GROUP BY DATEPART (mm, Date)
 ORDER BY MonNum
```

Comment: The question is specifically about Oracle SQL (pl/sql) which doesn't have a function DATEPART. I assume your code is for MS SQL Server (tsql)?

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle SQL to group by year and week number, use:

```
 GROUP BY to_char(createddate, 'IYYY IW')
```

Example output:

2022 46
2023 01