# show no of hours each week for specific project id sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this:

[image]

Now I want to see sum of hour for each week for each project .How can i query that.

I tried with query

```
select CurrentData.STATUS, 
    sum(CurrentData.HOURS), CurrentData.WEEKS 
from CURRENT_DATA CurrentData 
group by currentData.HOURS, CurrentData.STATUS, CurrentData.WEEKS, CurrentData.PROJECT_ID 
having currentData.WEEKS = CurrentData.WEEKS 
order by CurrentData.WEEKS;
```

But still each week coming as separate rows.Not sure how to do it

Comment: Here is something on [ask]; as starting point, please post sample data as formatted text, not images, trying to build a [mcve]; besides, you should post what you tried so far

Comment: I tried like this but it not giving me total for each week                                                                                                                                                                                                                       select CurrentData.STATUS, sum(CurrentData.HOURS),CurrentData.WEEKS
from CURRENT_DATA CurrentData
group by CurrentData.HOURS,CurrentData.STATUS,CurrentData.WEEKS,CurrentData.PROJECT_ID having CurrentData.WEEKS=CurrentData.WEEKS
order by CurrentData.WEEKS  ;

Comment: If you want to add information to your question (especially code) please edit your question to include it, rather then just commenting it.

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259633/oracle-sql-sum-and-group-data-by-week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259633/oracle-sql-sum-and-group-data-by-week)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Do not use HOURS in group by. The are in the group function SUM:

```
  SELECT PROJECT_ID, STATUS, YEARS, WEEKS, SUM (CurrentData.HOURS) 
    FROM CURRENT_DATA 
GROUP BY PROJECT_ID, STATUS, Years, WEEKS
ORDER BY Years, WEEKS
```

And what is in the having clause. That is always true. Do you want a certain week and year? And you can get rid of "CurrentData.". You have only one table and you don't need alias for this table.

Here filtered for year 2016 and summed for all project id :

```
  SELECT STATUS, WEEKS, SUM (CurrentData.HOURS) 
    FROM CURRENT_DATA 
   WHERE Years = 2016 
GROUP BY STATUS, WEEKS
ORDER BY WEEKS
```

Comment: And also: he is grouping by project_id, but that is not in the SELECT clause. It is in your solution (as it probably should be). And the grouping should be by year and week, not just by week (again, you did this correctly in your solution; the OP didn't).

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.But How to add where clause in it and how. For example.If i want for year 2016

Comment: One problem with query.It will return data of only one project id/

Comment: @williamjohn Changed for 2016

Comment: you can filter for project id too

Comment: But still its showing fr one project id.I want all project id.

Comment: @williamjohn Than you get rid from the project_id in the where clause. Changed